# Bootstrap collapse navbar on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have my Bootstrap navbar connected to my Wordpress navbar and all links work on desktop view. When in mobile view the navbar turns into a hamburger menu but I can not click it to show the menu.

header.php file:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>"<?php bloginfo('name')?></a>
          </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="menu">

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'Primary Nav',
                'depth'             => 3,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

fuctions.php file:
    <?php

function portfolio_enqueue() {
  //styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    //scripts
    wp_register_script('portfolio-js',
    get_template_directory_uri() .'/portfolio-js/portfolio.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('portfolio-js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portfolio_enqueue');

require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Nav' ),
) );

function portfolio_theme_setup() {
  add_theme_support('menus');
  register_nav_menus(array(
    'primary' => ('Primary Nav')
  ));
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or putting in wrong.

Comment: you should add `wp_register_script` for your `bootstrapjs` file

Comment: do I add both:  wp_register_script('bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');   ? If so that didn't work.

Comment: first of all if you want to use your own jquery version you have to dequeue the standard jquery loaded by wordpress like this `wp_dequeue_script('jquery');` and then register and enqueue your own script. More infos here: https://davidwalsh.name/remove-stylesheets

Comment: I'm okay with using Wordpress jquery. I'm looking for a way to make my custom styled Bootstrap menu work on my Wordpress site.